# Understand product attribute type multiselect

Tags: attributes, multiselect-attribute

Do you know why magento saves multiselect attribute type as `varchar` and relative product assocations in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` as **array**?

With array is not possible join between
`catalog_product_entity_varchar` and `eav_attribute_option_value` on `value=option_id`

when `value` is varchar like `1,2,3`, because `option_id` is int.

Isn't better considerer multiselect as multiple int and insert multiple record in `catalog_product_entity_int`?

So is possible join correctly `catalog_product_entity_int` and `eav_attribute_option_value` on `value=option_id`

Comment: I think that magento saves multiselect values in a string comma separated and not in multi int values, because it is stored in a single record and it is easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Multiselect attributes can be set as a comma separated list (or also an array) containing the attribute value ids.

So first we have to convert the actual values to Magento's internal ids.
try this code:-

```
$attrCode = 'color_base';
$sourceModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()
    ->getAttribute($attrCode)->getSource();
$valuesText = explode(',', 'red,green,blue');
$valuesIds = array_map(array($sourceModel, 'getOptionId'), $valuesText);
$product->setData($attrCode, $valuesIds);
$product->save();
```

link:-http://swarminglabs.com/how-to-change-a-product-dropdown-attribute-to-a-multi-select/

Comment: is possible to avoid that magento saves it as a comma separeted list and save it directly as single int like dropdown?

Comment: yes try it possible

Comment: and  visit link http://swarminglabs.com/how-to-change-a-product-dropdown-attribute-to-a-multi-select/

Comment: Ok, i try your code, but why magento don't has this logic by default and i have to do it with a custom code? My question was: why they use this logic to save multiselect in array?

Comment: i have begin in magento

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question: i don't want to know how to set or change to a multiselect attribute. I know how to do it and i know all about that. I don't understand **why magento use an ARRAY to save its value?**. With value saved in array is impossible to join the table on that column! Is my question clear?